# Is there an application for Windows7 (in bootcamp) to adjust the level of brightness of screen of iMac?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, imac, screen, display

I want to darken the screen of my iMac because it is too bright for me. I use an application called `shades`, but it doesn't work in bootcamp.

I found the software for Windows Vista called [`VistaShades`](http://vistashades.com) ([link](http://vistashades.com)). Is there a similar application for Windows7?

Comment: Have you tried VistaShades in Win7 and found that it doesn't work? The VistaShades website seems to suggest that it should work on at least XP SP2 as well, so perhaps it works for Win7 as well.

Comment: No, I haven't.
I'm gonna buy the os if I found the screen brightness problem can be solved.
It maybe works on XP as the website says, but I found some negative comments for Windows 7 on:
http://download.cnet.com/VistaShades/3000-2094_4-10840176.html
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2362557

Comment: OK. I'll be getting my own iMac in a few days, and I've already bought a Win7 license, so if no one else has an answer by then I'll try it out.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to test, but the comments above seem to be correct. VistaShades only dims the background windows/desktop in Win7, not the window you're currently working in, rendering it quite useless.

Comment: @Lizzan 
Thank you very much for testing!
That's very bad.
When i asked the question, 
actually i was trying to return to windows from mac because mac was difficult for me to use.
But after the question i found mac is very nice and easy.
And i decided to continue to use mac instead of windows.
Now, i've got one more reason why i do not use windows(the screen is bright on bootcamp).

Comment: Well, then I'm very glad you've started enjoying Mac OS X! Glad I could help. =D

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any software to do this. The Boot Camp drivers from Apple supports changing the brightness of the screen (using the keyboard modifier keys).

The drivers are already included in your Mac OS X DVD for installing Boot Camp Utilities. Otherwise, you can download the installation files using Boot Camp Assistant at `/Applications/Utilities`.

See [here](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for information.
Can the bootcamp drivers darken the screen completely?
Or it just can darken the screen to the same lowest brightness level as iMac's brightness control?
The lowest level of iMac's brightness control is still too bright for me.
(only a first few minutes, I can feel dark. but soon my eyes adapt the darkness and feel bright again.)
the software `shades` I use on OSX can darken screen completely(almost to black) and I can avoid overbrightness and eye strain and can keep my eyesight well.

Comment: @js_: so far i have not found any such software for windows. however, I do think that the lowest setting is extremely low and would not strain your eyes, unless you are in an extremely dark environment which will make your eyesight worst.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Bootcamp seems to have an inferiority complex. The solution that I have found to make Bootcamp brightness keys work properly is:

- Bootcamp.exe, Properties, Compatibility, Change settings for all users, Run this program as administrator.
- Remove startup item using msconfig for bootcamp (as startup items don't work with run as admin)
- Then create a Task Schedule for Bootcamp run as admin.

Answer (score 1):

Even without Apple's BootCamp, you can still dim your screen brightness with the help of the [Mac Brightness Control](http://www.macbrightness.com/product.html) software utility. However, it's NOT free.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Apple wireless keyboard, The F1 and F2 buttons dim and brighten the screen.